# Why isn't the Go etcd client releasing a lock?

Tags: go, locking, etcd

I am using the [Golang etcd client](https://pkg.go.dev/go.etcd.io/etcd/clientv3) to interact with etcd. [Here is an example](https://pkg.go.dev/go.etcd.io/etcd/clientv3/concurrency#example-Mutex.Lock) from the official documentation for obtaining and releasing locks.

I am building a request handler that is supposed to obtain a lock on a key in etcd, put a value in the key, then release the lock. The put completes without an error but the lock is not releasing.

Here is a simplification of my code. Assume the following variables:

- `etcdClient` is a `*clientv3.Client` that I'm sharing across the application.
- `keyToLock` is a `string`
- `valueToPut` is a `string`

```
func myHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    session, _ := concurrency.NewSession(etcdClient)
    defer session.Close()

    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), time.Second*5)
    defer cancel()

    mutex := concurrency.NewMutex(session, keyToLock)
    mutex.Lock(ctx)
    defer mutex.Unlock(ctx)

    etcdClient.Put(ctx, keyToPut, valueToPut)
}
```

I have tried the following things already:

- Moving the code that creates a session (and defers its closing) after the context creation code.
- Closing the session, cancelling the context, and unlocking the mutex directly (as opposed to deferring). None of these functions return any errors when calling them directly.

Comment: Why are you ignoring the return errors? This may have a clue…

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I omitted those errors for keeping my post simple. I checked those errors, and there were none. Right at the end of the post, I mentioned "None of these functions return any errors when calling them directly."